# How to read XML file in Javascript (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm working on getting info for an artist from last.fm servers and I need to be able to read the picture of the artist they have on their servers. You can view an example XML return statement [here](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=ac74a1e6fae52bc5f55a8a6f30b84db9). As you can see, there are many images for each artist (small, medium, large, extralarge, and mega). I need to be able to ready any of these and get the appropriate value back.

I'm new to reading XML/DOM through Javascript, so I'm sure it's fairly simple, but the extra attribute of "size" in the XML file is throwing me for a bit of a loop. Thanks!

Comment: was there a particular size you needed? or just all of them?

Answer (score 1):

This gets the first image for example.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=ac74a1e6fae52bc5f55a8a6f30b84db9",
type: "GET",
dataType: "html",
success: function(data) {

 var xml = $.parseXML(data)
    $(xml).each(function()
    {
     alert($(this).find("lfm>artist>image[size]:first").text());
    }); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
      // debug here
      alert("failure");
    }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use $.parseXML to create a kind of x-document.. then you can find stuff from it with jquery selectors.

```
 getXMLNode(retObj.responseXML, "thatField");

 function getXMLNode(xml, nameOfField) {
        return $($.parseXML(xml)).find(':first').find(nameOfField).text();
    }
```

Comment: Can you make the function more specific to my question? Like I said, each artist has 4 images attached to it and has an attribute of "size". I need to be able to access them by the "size" attribute. Look at the link I provided in my original post if you haven't already.

Comment: Ehh.. try this and check the log.. surely this has you on the right track?? you can traverse the xml the same way as athe DOM after calling the parseXML function. `$.each($($.parseXML(xml)), function(ind,val) { console.log($(val).html());  console.log($(val).find('image').attr('size'));  });`

Answer (score 0):

Something to this effect should return all image sizes:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=ac74a1e6fae52bc5f55a8a6f30b84db9",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        // Parse the xml file and get data
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $xml.find('image').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).text())
        });
    }
});
```